# Spring boot+Web mvc+JPA using CrudRepository giving issue on insert of a row using save method throwing EntityExistsException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Among CRUD operation Create is giving error of  "**A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session**" Rest all (Read, Update and Delete) is working fine.

Im using oracle sql as database and there is one more entity of product with many to one mapping with categories class.
**EntityClass**

```
@Entity
public class Categories {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Categories() {
        super();
    }

    public Categories(Integer id,String name) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public Categories(String name) {

        this.name=name;
    }
//with setters and getters
}
```

**JSP page**

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('name').disabled = true;document.getElementById('hidden').disabled = true;">

    <div align="center">
        <h4>Add or Modify or Delete Categories</h4>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/categories" modelAttribute="categories">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                    <td>

                        <form:select path="name">
                            <form:option value="NONE" label="Select" />
                            <form:options items="${categoriesList}" />
                        </form:select>

                    </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Operations</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="Ops" value="Add" checked="checked" onclick="document.getElementById('name').disabled = true; document.getElementById('newName').disabled = false;document.getElementById('hidden').disabled = true;">Add</input><br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="Ops" value="Modify"  onclick="document.getElementById('name').disabled = false; document.getElementById('newName').disabled = false;document.getElementById('hidden').disabled = true;">Modify</input><br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="Ops" value="Delete"  onclick="document.getElementById('name').disabled = false; document.getElementById('newName').disabled = true;document.getElementById('hidden').disabled = false;">Delete</input><br/>                   
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="newName" id="newName"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="newName" value="dummy"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller Class**

```
    @Controller
public class CategoriesController {
    @Autowired
    private CategoriesService cservice;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView categories() {
        // view name  model 
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("categories", "categories", new Categories());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String  opsOnCategories(@ModelAttribute("categories") Categories cat,@RequestParam("Ops") String ops,@RequestParam("newName") String name) 
    {
        if(ops.equals("Modify"))
        {
            cservice.modifyCategory(new Categories(Integer.parseInt(cat.getName()), name));
        }else if(ops.equals("Add"))
        {
            cservice.addCategory(new Categories(name));
        }else 
        {
            cservice.deleteCategory(Integer.parseInt(cat.getName()));
        }

        return "categories";
    }


    @ModelAttribute("categoriesList")
       public Map<String, String> getCategoryList() {
          Map<String, String> categoriesList = new HashMap<String, String>();
          List<Categories> ls=cservice.getAll();
          for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++)
          {
              categoriesList.put(ls.get(i).getId().toString(), ls.get(i).getName());
          }
          return categoriesList;
       }
}
```

Can anyone please help on this.

**Previous one due to which there was error**

```
insert into CATEGORIES(ID,NAME) values (1,'Mobile');
insert into CATEGORIES(ID,NAME) values (2,'Laptop');
```

**Changes made to remove error*

```
insert into CATEGORIES(ID,NAME) values (hibernate_sequence.nextval,'Mobile');
insert into CATEGORIES(ID,NAME) values (hibernate_sequence.nextval,'Laptop');
```

Comment: I missed out to mention that I was using import.sql with some insert queries, which was not using hibernate_sequence due to which there was miss-match in hibernate_sequence and latest primary key inserted

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is that there something wrong with @Id @GeneratedValue with Oracle Database specifically.

There are couple of things that you can do:

1- Try to connect to any other Database type just to test the functionality - so that you can rule out what doesn't matter

2- Try to use the @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id alongside with the @Id of javax persistence

Something that look like this

```
@Id
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
private Integer id;
```

3- Create a class that Generates random Integer Ids and refer to it using the annotations (@GenericGenerator & @GeneratedValue)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried changing database to build in database provided by spring boot (H2) but it is giving the same issue.After following step 2 I got run time exception of No identifier specified for entity. And I had a doubt of will 3rd suggestion help in case of getting unique values in each addition.

Comment: with regards to option #2 : you should have both Annotations Id of javax and id of spring: I have edited my answer above

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I missed out to mention that I was using import.sql with some insert queries, which was not using hibernate_sequence due to which there was miss-match in hibernate_sequence and latest primary key inserted.